# embedding/integrating Pentaho Data Integration into web applications?

Tags: java, web-applications, pentaho, etl, kettle

I would like to let the user use the transformation file created from the Pentaho data integration without the need of using the PDI application (spoon) and I want it to run on web application. For example when the user clicks or triggers the PDI File in the web application the `.ktr` or the created transformation file will run automatically.

Since I am new to PDI, can someone give me a link or step by step guide on how to do this? All the links that I have found are either incomplete or they are hard to follow.

Comment: You can launch transformation with kitchen.sh. What I do is to host a web service that provides an API call for user to trigger a transformation.

Comment: Do you really need to embed? Or could you just use carte?  Either way I'd imagine that carte would be a good place to start looking..

Answer (score 0):

you can expose your transformation as a web service with carte server

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/PDI+data+over+web+services